# apt-add-repository: command not found error in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I just made a very simple Docker file in my terminal, basically I did the following:

```
mkdir pgrouted
cd pgrouted
touch Dockerfile
```

Now I open the Docker file in the [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) editor, and I add the following commands to the Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER Gautam <gautamx07@yahoo.com>

LABEL Description="pgrouting excercise" Vendor="skanatek" Version="1.0"

ENV BBOX="-122.8,45.4,-122.5,45.6"

# Add pgRouting launchpad repository
RUN sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
RUN sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
RUN sudo apt-get update

# Install pgRouting package (for Ubuntu 14.04)
RUN sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting

# Install osm2pgrouting package
RUN sudo apt-get install osm2pgrouting

# Install workshop material (optional, but maybe slightly outdated)
RUN sudo apt-get install pgrouting-workshop

# For workshops at conferences and events:
# Download and install from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/wiki/Live_GIS_Workshop_Install
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting/+files/pgrouting-workshop_2.0.6-ppa1_all.deb

RUN sudo dpkg -i pgrouting-workshop_2.0.6-ppa1_all.deb

# Review: Not sure weather this should be in the dockerfile
RUN cp -R /usr/share/pgrouting/workshop ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop

# Log in as user "user"
RUN psql -U postgres

# Create routing database
RUN CREATE DATABASE routing;

# Add PostGIS functions
RUN CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

# Add pgRouting core functions
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;

# Download using Overpass XAPI (larger extracts possible than with default OSM API)
wget --progress=dot:mega -O "sampledata.osm" "http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[bbox=${BBOX}][@meta]"
```

The entire Dockerfile can be see **[HERE](http://chopapp.com/#yd9pqtlj)** at a glance.

Now when I try to build the Dockerfile, like so:

```
docker build -t gautam/pgrouted:v1 .
```

The Dockerfile runs and then I get the below error:

```
Step 4 : RUN sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
 ---> Running in c93c3c5fd5e8
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 206):

`apt-add-repository` is just not in the base Ubuntu image. You'll first need to install it. try `apt-get install software-properties-common`

By the way, you don't need to use `sudo` in the Dockerfile because the commands run as root by default unless you change to another user with the `USER` command.

Comment: i did add `pt-get install software-properties-common` as the first `RUN pt-get install software-properties-common` command , like so , now i get this error http://chopapp.com/#8a4vdsnw

Comment: depending upon you Ubuntu version, it can be either `python-software-properties` or `software-properties-common`

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04 this wants to install 46MiB additional data :/ too much to be able to execute a simple command.

Comment: Neither python-software-properties nor software-properties-common are valid

Comment: If this still gives error, first try `apt-get update` then `apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: Just for those who are still getting some error. I solved by putting update and install on the same line: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common`.
Running the update first and then install doesn't seem to work. Possibly a Docker bug

Comment: Always put `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` into the same `RUN` in Docker to avoid caching issues where the `apt-get install` is executed with respect to old package metadata. If you re-execute the `apt-get install` you always want to also re-execute the `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 94):

Add these lines before running `apt-add-repository` command

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: I had to add --fix-missing to the first line.

Comment: The `rm` undoes the effects of the `apt-get update`. There is no point in storing the package metadata in the container layer. If you later want to `apt-get install` additional packages, you should do a new `apt-get update` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```bash
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt install -y nginx php7.4-fpm php7.4-mysql php7.4-curl net-tools telnet php7.4-gd php-mail php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-curl php7.4-intl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-mysql php7.4-gd php7.4-xml php7.4-cli php7.4-zip php7.4-soap unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt clean
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).