# Can't install hadoop in a dockerfile which has ubuntu as base image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hadoop, dockerfile, docker-image

When I run the following code, I get this error, E: Unable to locate package hadoop

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
 && apt-get install python3.8 -y
RUN apt-get install jupyter -y
RUN apt-get install hadoop -y
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ADD sample.py /
LABEL maintainer=Ammar
CMD [ "python", "./sample.py" ]
```

Comment: Even if you install Hadoop packages, this won't start Hadoop processes, so what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a docker image which has python, jupyter, jenkins and hadoop.

Comment: You shouldn't run HDFS datanodes, namenodes, and YARN in the same container... Here's an example repo of mine that separates them https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/tree/master/hadoop-spark

Answer (score 0):

This link: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-apache-hadoop-hbase-on-ubuntu-linux/ contains full example of Hadoop installation. I think the same should be done in Docker step-by-step.

`apt-get install hadoop` not working in ubuntu without adding external repositories. But if you know external repo, then you must add `softwaree-properties-common` package (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52091668/1852444)
and then add your repository by `apt-add-repository` command.

Answer (score 0):

Some "foss" softwares and Softwares which do not comes under [foss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) are not added in ubuntu repository so they cannot be install using `apt` because `apt` use these repositories to install package.

hadoop is one of these packages which is not added to ubuntu repo. For more info about repository you can check [here](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-repositories/)

You can pull and use one of the hadoop container image created and pushed in [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=hadoop&type=image) by others instead of creating it for scratch.

If you still want to create your own hadoop container image you can check out [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/dockerfile) example hadoop [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/dockerfile)

Comment: Hadoop is FOSS / Apache licensed, so not clear about your first statements

Comment: hadoop is `foss` but still some software even after they are `foss` are not included by `ubuntu`